# Choosing between "Mirar" and "Ver"

Tags: selección-de-palabras, uso-de-palabras

What is the real difference between "**Ver**" and "**Mirar**". They are quite close in meaning but what are the differences between them? What are the rules to know whether we should choose one or the other?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

> "Mirar" emphasizes the **act**  (to see, as "to look at")
>
> "Ver" emphasizes the **perception**  (to see, as "to perceive")

In some cases, only one of these is acceptable. In many cases, both can be used.

Examples:

> "¿Me estás mirando?"  (Are you looking at me? a-la Taxi driver)
>
> "Con estos lentes no veo nada" (With these lens I don't see a thing)
>
> "¿Qué película estás viendo/mirando?" (What movie are you watching?)

Comment: In some cases, either works but with a different meaning.

"Mire al niño, por favor." - "Watch the child, please."
"Viste al niño?" - "Did you see the child?"

Answer (score 3):

The difference is related to your degree of concentration on the object.

"Ver" only implies your eyes are receiving light from the near objects, not a real attention to what you are seeing. If you start to look at something, that's "mirar". Anyway, the converse is not necessarily true, you could use "ver" if you are paying attention to something, but maybe not-too-much atention. However, in all cases it follows this order relationship for the degree of attention: **Ver < Mirar**

According to the RAE:

> [ver](http://buscon.rae.es/draeI/SrvltConsulta?LEMA=ver)

1. tr. Percibir por los ojos los objetos mediante la acción de la luz.
2. tr. Percibir algo con cualquier sentido o con la inteligencia.

> [mirar](http://buscon.rae.es/draeI/SrvltConsulta?LEMA=mirar)

1. tr. Dirigir la vista a un objeto. U. t. c. prnl.
2. tr. Observar las acciones de alguien.

The difference degree of attention is also clear in the definitions.

For example, If you want to request another person's attention to some object, you would say "mira eso" no "ve eso". Actually, "ve eso" more usually is figurative to "take charge of that".

Comment: I'm not sure if this is true in english, but I think is something like:
see < look/watch < observe. Am I correct?

Comment: So when I'm "viendo la television", am I just receiving light from it?

Comment: Actually, I was thinking exactly in that example. Both, "ver la televisión" and "mirar la televisión" are common. Sometimes TV is just a light and noise in the background, isn't it?. Anyway, I think is more important the order relationship. If you are lost in your thougts, people say to you "ey, mírame" no "ey, veme". "Mirar" requires a degree of atention "ver" doesn't.

Comment: "Ver" is short than "mirar", that's maybe the main reason to be used as interchangeble in some cases, but if you ask "¿estás viendo o mirando la TV?" and people is really watching a show, the aswer will be "estoy mirando".

Comment: At least in Spain, "ver la tele" is much more used than "mirar la tele" for watching a show (so in this case "ver" is used for a long activity which requires a lot of attention). Also it's really uncommon in Spain "mirar una película", "mirar un partido de fútbol". We use "ver" in that cases and a lot of attention is neccesary.

Comment: In Perú, is more common to say "mirar un partido de fútbol", fútbol is very important around here. About "ver la tele", probably it's a bit more common than "mirar la tele". However, "¿vamos a ver una película?" is by far more usual. Beside that, I think the differences are more clear in other contexts. I can't think in another dubious case, can you?. You always say "mira el paisaje" or "mira mi nuevo reloj".

Comment: @Ricardo the "attention" difference is not valid in all cases, there are many exceptions. it's a very simplistic answer for a complex aspect.

Comment: @Juanillo, could you said an example where the degree of attention is not related to the difference? I don't think the difference is complex. The problem is native speakers sometimes misuse the language in informal situations, but if you want to use the language properly, the choices are clear. Look at the the main definition for each verb.

Comment: @Ricardo The exceptions are with performances, shows and events (at least in Spain and as per comments in other countries too). It's more common to say "ver" with things like movies, sport events, TV, artistic performances while you're paying a lot of attention to them.

Comment: Ok, but that's the only exception I can think. And in some countries "mirar" is more used. On the other hand, there are a lot of cases where you can't interchange "ver" y "mirar: "Estoy ciego, ¡no puedo ver! (here, you are refering to "ver" as a basic sensorial activity, which is the main meaning of "ver").

Comment: You could update the answer with some of the things included here: http://spanish.about.com/od/usingparticularverbs/qt/ver_mirar.htm

Answer (score 0):

The following translations are pretty accurate:

Ver: watch, see

- Watch a film: ver una película
- Let's see what happens: vamos a ver qué pasa
- I didn't see him coming: no le vi venir

Mirar: look at

- What are you looking at? Qué estás mirando
- Look at that! ¡Mira eso!

Comment: I agree with see=ver and look=mirar, but totaly disagree with watch=ver. I would translate "watch this" by "mira esto" or even "observa esto". In english you say always "watch a movie" not "look a movie" as possible in spanish, so TV and movies are not the best example. 

"Watch this fish seek refuge in the anus of a sea cucumber!" : "¡Mira este pez buscar refugio en el ano de un pepino de mar!", "Ve este pez buscar refugio...", no way. "Observa este pez..." could be even a good translation.

Comment: In Mexico, people always *ver* movies and TV.  Perhaps the use of *mirar* for these actions is regional?

Comment: I agree Ricardo that this is not always true. Anyway it would be better to explain the difference without using a mapping with English so it could be useful for native students of other languages.